# Stream system audio to other devices over the network

Tags: audio, raspbian, alsa, pulseaudio, streaming

What are the possible ways to stream system audio to other devices?
mainly I'm looking for a way to stream audio from a kodi (running on raspbian or libreelec...etc) to a smartphone (ios) to use the smartphone as a wireless headphone.I've found some ways around the internet none of which worked for me.

mainly the reference for my idea is [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Wifi-Headphone-Using-a-Smartphone-for-Kodi/?ALLSTEPS).

some other ways i've read about are `pulseaudio` network, jack, icecast and shoutcast.

so how to accomplish this the right way

**UPDATE:** One way that worked is using [pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna) and using a upnp media renderer such as bubbleupnp but it's not stable enough(audio lose sync)